# Issue returning the nested object in JSON

Tags: json, node.js

I am using the following function code to try and return the "sportId" but am not getting anything.

```
   function (err, response, body) {
     // parse the body as JSON
     var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);

     var apiResults = parsedBody.apiResults;
     var sportId = apiResults.sportId;
     res.json(sportId);
});
```

Below is the result when I return just parsedBody.

```
{"status":"OK","recordCount":1,"startTimestamp":"2017-05-09T21:01:17.9462907Z","endTimestamp":"2017-05-09T21:01:18.1533299Z","timeTaken":0.20703919999999998,"apiResults":[{"sportId":2,"name":"Baseball","league":{"leagueId":7,"name":"Major League Baseball" ...
```

It also works when I return apiResults, just not for some reason when I try to get sportId.  I am new to node.js and cannot figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apiResults` is an array of objects. `sportId` is in that object so you need to use the loop to traverse the `sportId`

If you want to retrieve the first one then use

```
var sportId = apiResults[0].sportId
```

Comment: ahh, thank you.  There was only one instance in the array, so I missed that.